# How do I obtain the first fundamental form in terms of the arclength and unit normal of an arbitrary ray in the real plane?

Tags: differential-equations

My question is based on the 1981 paper "Computation of wave fields in inhomogenous media" by Cerveny *et.al.* (I will add any appropriately needed information to this posted question, so there is no need to obtain the paper).

They search for solutions to the wave equation

$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial{x^2}} + \frac{\partial^2u}{\partial{z^2}} = \frac{1}{V(x,z)^2}\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial{t^2}}$$

where $V(x,z)$ is known. The $\mathbb{R}^2$ Cartesian coordinates $(x,z)$ are used. An arbitrary ray $\Omega \subset \mathbb{R}^2$ (not necessarily straight) is taken, and parameterized by arclength $s$ increasing from an initial point $s = 0$ at $t = 0$. The real plane is parameterized based on $\Omega$ by the arclength $s$ and the unit normal $n$ off the ray.

For non-straight rays $\Omega$ there are irregular regions (where different pairs $(s,n)$ that describe the same point in $\mathbb{R}^2$), and the complement in $\mathbb{R}^2$ is called the regularity region.

They then obtain the first fundamental form in terms of a small segment $dr$ of arclength as

$$dr^2 = h^2 ds^2 + dn^2$$

where

$$h = 1 + \frac{n}{v}v_n$$

for $v(s) = V(s,0)$ and

$$v_n = \left[\frac{\partial V(s,n)}{\partial n}\right]_{n=0}.$$

My question: **How did they obtain the first fundamental form?** I know that

$$dr^2 = F_s{\cdot}F_s ds^2 + 2F_s{\cdot}F_n ds dn + F_n{\cdot}F_n dn^2$$

where $F(s,n) = (x,z)$ is the coordinate transformation and $F_k$ is the first derivative of $F$ wrt $k$ for $k \in \left\{s,n\right\}$. However, they obtain the first fundamental form with arbitrary array $\Omega$.

Let me know if you need more information.

Reference: Červený, Vlastislav, Mikhail M. Popov, and Ivan Pšenčík. "Computation of wave fields in inhomogeneous media—Gaussian beam approach." *Geophysical Journal International 70*.1 (1982): 109-128.

Comment: Isn't it $dr^2 = F_s\cdot F_s ds^2 + 2F_s\cdot F_n ds dn + F_n\cdot F_n dn^2$?